# setup.py console_scripts entry point does not resolve import

Tags: python, setuptools

I have following setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    name="foobar",
    version="0.1.0",
    author="Batman",
    author_email="batman@gmail.com",
    packages = ["foobar"],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        "asyncio",
    ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foobar = foobar.__main__:main'
         ]
    },
)
```

Now, the **main**.py file gets installed and callable by foobar out of console after installation, which is what I wanted. Problem is, **main**.py has import at line 3 and that does not work.

So my folder structure is as follows

```
dummy/setup.py
dummy/requirements.txt
dummy/foobar/__init__.py
dummy/foobar/__main__.py
dummy/foobar/wont_be_imported_one.py
```

I run `python3 setup.py bdist` being in dummy directory.
Upon running foobar after installation, I get error

```
File "/usr/local/bin/foobar", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('foobar==0.1.0', 'console_scripts', 'foobar')()

[...]

ImportError: No module named 'wont_be_imported_one'.
```

UPDATE.
`__init__.py` has content of

```
from wont_be_imported_one import wont_be_imported_one
```

`wont_be_imported_one.py` has from `wont_be_imported_one` function which I actually need to import.

Comment: `__init__.py` contents ?

Comment: from wont_be_imported_one import wont_be_imported_one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3, `import`s are absolute by default, and so `from wont_be_imported_one import ...` inside of `foobar` will be interpreted as a reference to some module named `wont_be_imported_one` outside of `foobar`.  You need to use a relative import instead:

```
from .wont_be_imported_one import wont_be_imported_one
#    ^ Add this
```

See [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more information.